# True and false questions whether combinations of entire functions are still entire functions

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

> Let $f,g$ be entire functions. Decide which of the following are still entire functions.
>
> (a) $f(z)^3$
>
> (b) $(fg)(z)$
>
> (c) $(f/g)(z)$
>
> (d) $5f(z) + ig(z)$
>
> (e) $f(1/z)$
>
> (f) $g(z^2 + 2)$
>
> (g) $f(g(z))$

My thoughts are

(a) Yes, since $(f(z)^3)' = 3f'(z)f(z)^2$  and so on and so on for any $n$.

(b) This follows from product rule I believe.

(c) Not if $f(z) = g(z) = x$. Then we would get $\frac{f(z)}{g(z)} = \frac{x}{x}$. So not true.

(d) Sums of differentiable functions.

(e) $f(z) = x$ is a counter example like above. All use real analysis.

(f) I think this is chain rule again, but I can't see why translations would make a function not entire.

(g) Chain rule again.

Comment: Neither of those are statements, you can't attribute a truth value to functions.

Comment: @GitGud, I got this from a book. The book is written by "Saff and Snider"

Comment: @sidht I edited the question following the suggestion of Git.  So all those are complete statements.

Comment: What do you mean by $f(z)=x$?  Is it a typo for $f(z)=z$, or do you mean that $f(z)$ should be the real part of $z = x+iy$?  The latter is not an entire function.

Comment: It would probably be clearer in (c) to use $f(z)=1$ and $g(z)=z$, because in complex analysis we tend to ignore removable singularities. Otherwise your answers are fine, assuming you have typos where I think you have typos (e.g. $f(z)=z$ rather than $f(z)=x$).

Comment: I think that (c) and (e) can be non entire functions. All the others are still entire functions. According to my understanding, entire functions are equivalent to Taylor expansion. You can check if any combination from (a) to (g) still preserves the Taylor expansion property of $f(z)$ and $g(z)$, then it is an entire function.

Comment: @everyone, I did mean $f(z) = Re(z) = x.$ And I forgot that $x$ is not entire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entire functions are closed under composition, +, -, * and positive integer powers.  This will get a few.